# spring-boot rest application on weblogic

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, weblogic12c

I have a spring boot rest application working fine on Tomcat.
My goal was to deploy the same on weblogic. I have followed the steps mentioned on spring site [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

I don't have a web.xml file in the project.
After deployment I ran into this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: 
Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, 
or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating with
in a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside 
of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener 
or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
        at org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder.currentR
equestAttributes(RequestContextHolder.java:131) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:
4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

The same requests work fine in tomcat. I am not sure if I need to include a web.xml file with ContextLoaderListener. But I wonder how it's not a problem in tomcat container.

Comment: Using the same code with Tomcat and then Weblogic may not work because of specificities of each one. Spring Boot and Weblogic : the unlikely marriage...

Comment: The issue is happening for @autowired HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in a bean. On Weblogic accessing the request or response object is throwing this error.

Comment: Imho you shouldn’t be autowiring the request and response but rather pass them as a method argument. That being said WebLogic ships with its own version of Spring and you need to include a weblogic specific deployment descriptor to make the classes from your application preferred to those from the server.

Comment: Finally got it working adding RequestContextFilter using addBefore on the WebSecurityConfig class. Still not sure what tomcat does differently that it was not needed